# XlsxWriter - Create chart with more than two Y axis

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, python-2.5

As the post's title says I'm looking for a way to create a line chart with more then two Y axis with XlsxWriter module. Is this possible? From the documentation there is no record about three or more Y axis.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Hi @C.Bertulli, could you post the code of what you have tried so far? So that it'll be easier to point you to the right direction....

Comment: Is that possible in Excel?

Comment: Hi @toti08, there is no code jet. I've read the documentation and found nothing about three Y axis, this is why I'm asking here, maybe someone achieving it.

Comment: @C.Bertulli There is still the question of whether this is possible in Excel. AFAIK it isn't so it won't be possible in XlsxWriter.

Comment: @jmcnamara Yes, I searched over the web and found that is not possible :/.